# Getting Flutter Cupertino_icons dependency Error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error in my project. I even created a new plain flutter project but I am getting the same error for that too.

I even tried clearing the flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cupertino_icons -****. I even tried giving version name specifically. But still it dowent workRunning "flutter pub get" in abccdddd...                            1.0s
Launching lib\main.dart on SM J600G in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

```
Compiler message:
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:1:1: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
We:
^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:1:1: Error: Expected ';' after this.
We:
^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:1:3: Error: Expected a declaration, but got ':'.
We:
  ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:1: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '-'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:10: Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'this'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
         ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:10: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
         ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:15: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
              ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:15: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
              ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:20: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                   ^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:20: Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'in'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                   ^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:20: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                   ^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:23: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                      ^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:23: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                      ^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:29: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                            ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:29: Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'for'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                            ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:29: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                            ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:37: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                    ^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:47: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                              ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:49: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                                ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:49: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                                ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:52: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '/'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                                   ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:54: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:65: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                                                ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:1: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '-'.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:8: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
       ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:8: Error: 'a' is already declared in this scope.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
       ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:47: Context: Previous declaration of 'a'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                              ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:10: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
         ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:10: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
         ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:10: Error: 'lib' is already declared in this scope.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
         ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:49: Context: Previous declaration of 'lib'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                                ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:13: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '/'.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
            ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:25: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                        ^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:32: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                               ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:44: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                           ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:44: Error: 'a' is already declared in this scope.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                           ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:8: Context: Previous declaration of 'a'.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
       ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:46: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                             ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:46: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                             ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:50: Error: Expected a declaration, but got '-'.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                                 ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:68: Error: Expected ';' after this.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                                                   ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:68: Error: 'file' is already declared in this scope.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                                                   ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:15: Context: Previous declaration of 'file'.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
              ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:3: Error: Type 'commit' not found.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
  ^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:33: Error: Type 'git' not found.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:40: Error: Type 'create' not found.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                       ^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:3: Error: Type 'want' not found.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
  ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:15: Error: 'directory' isn't a type.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
              ^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:54: Context: This isn't a type.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:28: Error: Type 'pub' not found.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                           ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:37: Error: Type 'create' not found.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                    ^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:51: Error: Type 'formed.packages' not found.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:3: Error: 'commit' isn't a type.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
  ^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:33: Error: 'git' isn't a type.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:2:40: Error: 'create' isn't a type.
- commit this file in order for git to create a lib/ directory, and
                                       ^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:3: Error: 'want' isn't a type.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
  ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:28: Error: 'pub' isn't a type.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                           ^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:37: Error: 'create' isn't a type.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                    ^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt:3:51: Error: 'formed.packages' can't be used as a type because 'formed' isn't defined.
- want a lib/ directory so pub will create a well-formed .packages file
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\Flutter Apps\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'E:\Flutter Apps\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

[image]

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: You should probably install flutter again

Answer (score 0):

I opened .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cupertino_icons-0.1.3/lib/placeholder.txt file and cleared it. And it started working for me. Really odd, but it did.